# How to retrieve xml root element all attributes in php?

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml like this:

```
<ns2:HotelRhg xmlns:ns2="http://v3.abc.somexyz.com/" size="6">
<hotelId>340194</hotelId>
<arrivalDate>03/06/2012</arrivalDate>
 ....
```

I want to retrieve  first line (root element) attributes like "size" and its value. I used

```
$xml->getDocNamespaces(TRUE);
```

but am getting only ns2="http://v3.abc.somexyz.com/" and not size=6

so please anybody can sort out this using PHP

Comment: Did you really expect `getDocNamespaces` to return something *other than namespaces*?

Answer (score 1):

`Simplexml_load_string()` is the solution

```
  $string = <<<XML
 <ns2:HotelRhg xmlns:ns2="http://v3.abc.somexyz.com/" size="6">
 <hotelId>340194</hotelId>
 <arrivalDate>03/06/2012</arrivalDate>
  XML; 

 $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
   foreach($xml->ns2[1]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
   echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
```

If you simply want size then do the following instead of iteration

```
       $attributes = $xml->ns2[0]->attributes(); //collection of all attributes in ns2
       <b><?=$attributes['size'] ?></b>  // in your html
```

Comment: It implies :Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object. If I call ->attributes to child nodes am able to fetch but while using ->attributes() to root element am not able fetch.